# Facebook api Curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, upload, image

I have a probelm with my cUrl it doesnt seem to work could someone help me please?

i tried with file_get_contetn but it didnt work :( i have an error with it
I have searcched everywhere but couldnt find anything :S

```
  <?php
              $app_id = "xxxxx";
              $app_secret = "xxxxx";
              $fanpage_id ='3xxxxx';

              $post_login_url = "xxxxxxxxxteszt.php";  


              $photo_url = "xxxxxxxxxx20130412104817.jpg";


              $photo_caption = "sasdasd";

          $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

          //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
          if (!$code)
          { 
            $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
              . "client_id=" .  $app_id
              . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
              .  "&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages";

            echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
              . "'</script>");
          } 
          if(isset($_REQUEST['code'] ))
          {
          print('<script>alert("asd");</script>');
              function curl($url){
               $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url );
                }
            $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
              . "client_id=" . $app_id
              . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
              . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
              . "&code=" . $code;

             print($code);
            $response = curl($token_url);
            print($response);
            $params = null;
            parse_str($response, $params);
            $access_token = $params['access_token'];

            // POST to Graph API endpoint to upload photos
            $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fanpage_id."/photos?"
              . "url=" . urlencode($photo_url)
              . "&message=" . urlencode($photo_caption)
              . "&method=POST"
              . "&access_token=" .$access_token;

            echo '<html><body>';

               echo curl($graph_url);

            echo '</body></html>';
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: It does not look like you are actually executing the curl request anywhere. You set it up with `$ch = curl_init()` but I don't see `curl_exec($ch)` in your code anywhere? Take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for an example. Also you may want to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change your curl function to

```
 function curl($url){
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     if($response === false)
     {
         echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
     }
     else
     {
         $response = $response;
     }         

     curl_close($ch);
     return $response;
 }
```

This will execute your curl request and print out the error if one occurs.

**EDIT**: I simplified the curl execution since you are formatting the string this is really going through as a get request so there is no need for the post options that you were setting up. Try this and see what you get.

Comment: i had an error with this... the first one was host not found... i changed the https to http than that was fixed.. but after that i got a 302 Found error

Comment: Curl error: couldn't connect to hostCurl error: couldn't connect to host
is the error if its https

Comment: I updated the function, simplified it since you are not actually doing a post. Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: is there a chance that my webhosting doesnt allow this?

Comment: Doubtful, especially since it is the facebook opengraph. What happens if you paste the URL in your browser? Do you get a json object printed on the screen?

Comment: yes i do but, https file_get_contetnts dont work on my site... so for expample youtubes works just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's a bit strange to declare your curl function in the middle of your 'if' statement, but secondly there are some basic elements missing in your curl function . . .

You initiate and you set options, but you do not execute! `url_exec($ch)` is missing in your curl function. The minimum use of curl should have this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Secondly your curl function does not have any output! so what is there to echo?

Your curl function should end with something like . . .
`return $output;`